# What are b and e in Solaris paritioning?

Tags: partition, solaris

I'm on Solaris 11, disk using EFI and GPT but with classical bios

```
  0  BIOS_boot    wm               256        260.00MB            532735
  1        usr    wm            532736          5.46TB            11721028750
  2 unassigned    wm                 0             0                 0
  3 unassigned    wm                 0             0                 0
  4 unassigned    wm                 0             0                 0
  5 unassigned    wm                 0             0                 0
  6 unassigned    wm                 0             0                 0
  8   reserved    wm       11721028751          8.00MB            11721045134
```

Are 532735 11721028750 and 11721045134 extents or cylinders?
When I change the numbers solaris ask to choose between `b` (blocks?) dimensions (gb,tb,mb..) and `e`(?).
Why are the called `e` and not `c`?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `prtvtoc` you will see the header of the table (for reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/prtvtoc-1m.html#scrolltoc)):

```
example# prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s2
* /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s2 partition map
*
* Dimension:
*     512 bytes/sector
*      80 sectors/track
*       9 tracks/cylinder
*     720 sectors/cylinder
*    2500 cylinders
*    1151 accessible cylinders
*
* Flags:
*   1: unmountable
*  10: read-only
* *                           First    Sector   Last
* Partition   Tag   Flags   Sector   Count    Sector   Mount Directory
     0         2     00          0    76320    76319   /
     1         3     01      76320   132480   208799
     2         5     00          0   828720   828719
     5         6     00     208800   131760   340559   /opt
     6         4     00     340560   447120   787679   /usr
     7         8     00     787680    41040   828719   /export/home
```

So you see these are start and end sector.

For the record the block size in Solaris is 512 bytes so the command `df` will give you the size in blocks, not like in Linux.